# Regex Get Matches excluding pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to create a regex which will return all special characters in a string except those which are preceeded/followed by whitespace. It should also exclude the final full stop.

e.g.

- Hello!This is a test. There is one match.
- This should!!!!match.
- This is not a match. There is a space after special char.

I was trying this but it is not what I need.

```
[^a-zA-z0-9\s](?!(\s[^a-zA-z0-9]|[^a-zA-z0-9]\s))
```

Comment: Should it match punctuation which appears as the first character in the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
(?<!\s)\p{P}(?!\s)(?!$)
```

That's:

- `(?<!\s)`: A negative lookbehind, asserting that we don't appear after whitespace
- `\p{P}`: The punctuation to match (that's the Unicode punctuation general category)
- `(?!\s)`: a negative lookahead, asserting that we don't appear before whitespace
- `(?!$)`: another negative lookahead, asserting that we don't appear before the end of the file

You could also do it without the lookaround assertions, and instead use a capturing group to pull out the punctuation character:

```
(?:[^\s]|^)(\p{P})[^\s$]
```

I've added a test which matches the beginning of the string to keep the same behaviour as the first regex when the punctiation character appears as the first character in the string. Your question doesn't specify the behaviour here.

Comment: This is almost perfect except it includes the closest alphanumeric character also.
e.g. Hello!This is a test. There is one match. the returned match is "o!T" where i just want to get the punction.

Comment: @user2433108 the first regex doesn't. For the second regex, you will need to look at the captured group (`Groups[1]`), rather than the whole match

Comment: found an issue where because it is using \p (punctuation) it does not work for all non alphanumeric characters - including plus, tilde, vertical bar.